# Customizing Addthis Button

Tags: javascript, addthis

http://www.moen.com/anabelle/spot-resist-stainless-one-handle-high-arc-pulldown-kitchen-faucet/_/R-CONSUMER%3ACA87003SRS?swatch=1

I want to have a single sharing button on my pages just like this page, the things I want are:
1)The popup compact menu is disabled
2)It doesn't add a floating side menu to the page
3)The HTML of the button on this page is

```
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=cmassmoen" title="Share this Page" class="icon-share addthis_button_more" addthis:url="" target="_blank">
  <img src="/assets/moencom/images/catalog/product-details/sharing/share.png" height="20" width="20">
 </a>
```

The HREF has a `v` parameter and `username` parameter in it (I look around on addthis website, but I couldn't find how to generate a button with similar href attribute)

I've read throught addthis's API page, but still not very sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, first you'll need an account with addThis. In the code below, I'm using [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) for the icon, but you can use whatever image you want. just replace the `<i>` tag with an `<img>` tag.

[Link to see this in action](https://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/zpeefpqy/).

Required

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="LINK-TO-YOUR-ADDTHIS-ACCOUNT" async="async"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

HTML

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="icon-share addthis_button_more"><i class="fa fa-share-alt fa-5x"></i></a>
</div>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

CSS

```
.icon-share {
    color:#ccc;
}
.icon-share:hover {
    color:#00A2D7;
}
```